# shrink sticks section

Tags: modeling

I have an object made from several sticks (boxes) I want to shrink the section of the sticks without changing the size of the whole thing, just thinner wood pieces. Is there a clever way to resize it in the proper way? If possible without redoing it, obviously xD [image]

Comment: press alt+s in x axis or y axis (any one axis)

Comment: In object mode alt+s reset scale. I don't want to enter edit mode because then I have to enter each stick separately

Comment: u can join all stick ctrl+J you can try in object model alt+s

Comment: ctrl+J was a great idea, now they are all together. alt +s seams to be doing something good but it keeps the x axis while modifying the other two. Is there a way to select the z axis ?

Comment: select z axis means i did not get